# Reset build number in Travis-CI

Tags: github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I'm using **Travis-CI** with **GitHub**.

I would like to know if is possible to **reset** the **build number** and/or delete the related Travis page.

I tried to delete my repo on GitHub but this is not affecting the related Travis page. 
Even if I create a new repo, with the same name of the previous, the build number starts from the previous one, and the builds are linking on 404 on GitHub. I know that isn't a big issue, but I would like to keep consistent all my solution.

Comment: That's not possible right now. But the Travis guys (who are awesome btw.) could probably implement that if you contact them and ask nicely :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately we don't have a way to delete repositories or builds. If any private data has been exposed, you can always email us to have the logs stripped.

We are working on a way to archive repositories, which basically means that they'll be hidden until a new build is run, see the [issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/987) for more information on that.